# Applying a persistent filter to a tablesorter table

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I would like to apply a persistent filter to a tablesorter table.

By this, I mean I would like to apply a filter in addition to the filters seen by the user. In other words, I want to make certain rows disappear as far as tablesorter is concerned, but I can't outright delete them as I need to be able to re-add them later.

The following demonstrates an attempt. While it appears to work, the hidden rows become visible when a filter becomes less restrictive. (e.g. Check the box, enter "B1" in the filter for column "B", then delete the "1".)

```js
$(function() {
   var $table = $('#table').tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue',
      widgets: [ "zebra", "filter" ],
      widgetOptions : {
      },
   });

   $('#hide_spoilers').change(function(){
      if (this.checked) {
         $table.find("tr.spoiler").hide();
         $table.trigger('applyWidgetId', 'zebra');
      } else {
         $table.find("tr.spoiler").show();
         // And somehow refresh the search here.
         $table.trigger('applyWidgetId', 'zebra');
      }
   });
});
```

```css
tr.spoiler td { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/dist/css/theme.blue.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/dist/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/dist/js//jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>

<p><label for="hide_spoilers">Hide Spoilers</label><input id="hide_spoilers" type="checkbox"></p>

<table id="table">
   <thead>
      <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td>A1</td><td>B1</td><td>C1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>A2</td><td>B2</td><td>C2</td></tr>
      <tr class="spoiler"><td>A3</td><td>B3</td><td>C3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>A4</td><td>B4</td><td>C4</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I also tried adding the `filtered` class to the rows, but it's no surprise that this doesn't work either.

This can be done using a hidden column, but that could mess with other features (such as `filter_reset`). Is there a native way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css specificity needs to be increased on the spoiler row:

I modified the following ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/1762/)):

HTML

```
<input id="hide_spoilers" type="checkbox" checked>
...
<tr class="spoiler hide"><td>A3</td><td>B3</td><td>C3</td></tr>
```

CSS

```
tr.spoiler td { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) }
tr.spoiler.hide { display: none; }
```

JS

```
$('#hide_spoilers').change(function(){
   if (this.checked) {
      $table.find("tr.spoiler").addClass('hide');
      $table.trigger('applyWidgetId', 'zebra');
   } else {
      $table.find("tr.spoiler").removeClass('hide');
      // And somehow refresh the search here.
      $table.trigger('applyWidgetId', 'zebra');
   }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I don't even to refresh the search

Comment: The ironic thing is that in my actual use-case, it's a select not a checkbox, and the other values of the select add classes. (`css_class = 'spoiler-'+value; $('.spoiler').addClass(css_class);`)